# How can I create an overlay that stays in DOM as opacity 0 but doesn't prevent content from being clickable?

Tags: jquery, css

I have created a preloader that I want to show and hide when required using CSS3 transitions, my problem however is my overlay is on top of all other elements preventing them from being clicked etc what i would like to do is use the CSS3 transition keeping the fade in out fade out smooth and soft, if I add `display: none` to .overlay and then `display:block` to `.overlay.is-active` this prevents the transition taking effect so wondering how I can achieve this without relaying on js to fade in and fade out? Also adding `pointer-events: none` would help a little but isnt widely supported and would prevent my close buttton from being clickable.

CSS

```
.overlay,
.loading {
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.overlay {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
   position: fixed;
   /* display: none; */
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
}

.overlay.is-active {
    /*display: block;*/ 
    opacity: 1;
}

.close {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: grey;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 200;
}

.loading {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejnpP/3/

Comment: If you want it not to show but also not to prevent clicking, so why you need that element?

Comment: set z-index in minus(-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using z-index you can push the overlay underneath other elements or put it back over the elements, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejnpP/4/

```
.overlay {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
   position: fixed;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
   z-index: -1;
}

.overlay.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

the exact values for z-index will depend on your page.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with the z-index:

```
.overlay {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    z-index: -1;
}

.overlay.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Or you could add a ontransitionend listener with javascript and set the display:none property when the overlay has finished transitioning

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/ejnpP/5/